# how to create presence/absence data frame with data of columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a data frame similar to

```
df <- data.frame(sp1=c("e1", "e2", "e4"), sp2=c("e1", "e3", "e4"), sp3=c("e2", "e3", "e5"))

  sp1 sp2 sp3
1  e1  e1  e2
2  e2  e3  e3
3  e4  e4  e5
```

So I want to construct a data frame of presence (1)/absence (0) similar to:

```
   sp1 sp2 sp3
e1  1   1   0
e2  1   0   1
e3  0   1   1
e4  1   1   0
e5  0   0   1
```

in this case all the sp elements has the same length, but in the real data could be that some columns present less or more elements: sp4=c("e1", "e3")

how can I construct the data frame (or matrix) ?

thanks so much !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract the unique levels from the data and use `sapply` with `table`.

```
lvls <- sort(unique(unlist(df)))
sapply(df, function(x) table(factor(x, lvls)))

#   sp1 sp2 sp3
#e1   1   1   0
#e2   1   0   1
#e3   0   1   1
#e4   1   1   0
#e5   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative `tidyverse` way without `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(x = paste(sp1, sp2, sp3, sep = ", ")) %>% 
  separate_rows(x) %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("sp"), ~ifelse(. == x, 1, 0))) %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  column_to_rownames("x")
```

```
   sp1 sp2 sp3
e1   1   1   0
e2   0   0   1
e3   0   1   1
e4   1   1   0
e5   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `mtabulate`

```
library(qdapTools)
t(mtabulate(df))
   sp1 sp2 sp3
e1   1   1   0
e2   1   0   1
e3   0   1   1
e4   1   1   0
e5   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` approach:

### Data

```
df <- data.frame(sp1=c("e1", "e2", "e4"), sp2=c("e1", "e3", "e4"), sp3=c("e2", "e3", "e5"))
```

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
```

### Code

```
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>% 
  #This separate if you have more than one value inside the cell
  separate_rows(value,sep = ",") %>% 
  #Auxiliary variable
  mutate(aux = 1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from = aux) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.),0)
```

### Result

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  value   sp1   sp2   sp3
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 e1        1     1     0
2 e2        1     0     1
3 e3        0     1     1
4 e4        1     1     0
5 e5        0     0     1
```

Answer (score 1):

A way will be to use `%in%`.

```
x <- sort(unique(unlist(df)))
data.frame(+sapply(df, `%in%`, x=x), row.names = x)
#   sp1 sp2 sp3
#e1   1   1   0
#e2   1   0   1
#e3   0   1   1
#e4   1   1   0
#e5   0   0   1
```